# pomfile setting in fitnesse

Tags: variables, fitnesse

!contents -R2 -g -p -f -h
Use Slim engine instead of Fit
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}

Change the default port to avoid conflicts
!define SLIM_PORT {62123}
I have following test in fitnesse.

My pomfile entries are not read. I am getting class not found execption on execution. Do we need anything to set up to read pom.xml

Classpath and pom file
!path C:\Users\myname\AnypointStudio\workspace\xxxxx\target\test-classes
!path C:\Users\myname\AnypointStudio\workspace\xxxxxx\target\classes
!pomFile C:\Users\myname\AnypointStudio\workspace\xxx\pom.xml

|import|
|com.mycompany.test|

!|script  |hello world|
|test hello world|

Comment: Any chance you have used a settings.xml file in the .m2 directory below your user directory to modify the location of the maven repository on your local disk? I've seen something similar once and the fix was to change the global settings (settings.xml in M2_HOME instead of in user directory).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have pom reader plugin to parse pom file in fitnesse.

http://github.com/amolenaar/fitnesse-maven-classpath